# OneDrive for business Oauth2 authentication

Tags: c#, ms-office, onedrive

I am trying to get access to OneDrive for Business using OAuth2.0 authentication protocol. I have followed this example: 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn605894(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn605894%28v=office.15%29.aspx) 
an this is my code so far:

```
        //  Create an authentication context
        AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}",
        ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(TenantIdClaimType).Value));

        String id = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(TenantIdClaimType).Value;

        //  Create a client credential based on the application id and secret.
        ClientCredential clcred = new ClientCredential(AppPrincipalId, AppKey);

        //  Using the authorization code acquire an access token.
        var arAD = ac.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, new Uri(appRedirect), clcred);
```

I am getting a Authorization code is malformed error. I don't understand why I am getting this message.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please don't mark your question as solved. Instead, post an answer with your solution and accept that answer. Now you removed it, and that is very confusing...

Comment: Hi,
Really sorry about the confusion. I solved the problem by implementing it in Java instead. I used the HttpClient 3.1 Post Method to get the authorization code, access taken and refresh token. Again I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when I was trying to get authorization code manually and then use it from console application. Not sure why it doesn't work for me.

But when I use it from Web App, the same app which performed authorization and received code in return (because I specified it as returnURL) - everything works.

I suggest you to have a look on this example

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OAuth2-UserIdentity-DotNet

And also this article to understand what's happening under the good:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx

P.S.
It's not a OneDrive, but I had exactly the same problem, so if you can make it working with Exchange or GraphApi, then it should work for OneDrive as well.

Answer (score 0):

Authorization code is malformed error is occured if you send the auth code in incorrect format. May be the authorization code which you are sending is encoded value of authcode and session state. you need to seperate both values and send the auth code only. or decode the '&' symbol(seperator) between auth code and session state and send them as two parameters.

The method **AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(...)** from ADAL4j takes only authcode.